# In yii2 how to change Dropdown data as per role from?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, html.dropdownlistfor

I have data in Drop down list as per role(for every role table are different).
I don't have any idea how to do because I am not familiar with yii2 First select a role and after selecting role I want data from different different table as per role

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'role')->dropDownList( [ 'A' => 'Admin', 'M' => 'Member', 'P' => 'Practice', ],['prompt'=>'--Select a Role--',]);?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'code')->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map(Member::find()->all(), 'id', 'memberCode'),           
                            ['id'=>'memberCode']
                        );
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Refer to [Kartik Dependent Drop Down in Yii2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop) ..This will surely helpfull

Answer (score 2):

You Need to update your 2nd dropdown when you select any value from dropdown 1st. Lets say 2nd drop down have id #dropdown2 so, i dit in yii you can change it according to yii2.

```
 echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                    $model, 'id', array(
                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(),
                'widgetOptions' => array(
                    'data' => CSystemGenerated::getProjectName($model->c_id),
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        'prompt' => 'Select Project',
                        'ajax' => array(
                                'type' => 'POST',
                                'url' =>  your url,
                                'update' => '#dropdown2',
                                //'dataType' => 'json',
                                'data'=>array('id'=>'js:this.value'),

                              )
                            ),
                        ),
              )
            );   

 <?php
            echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                    $model, 'tag', array(
                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(),
                'widgetOptions' => array(
                    'data' =>$this->getTags(),
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        'prompt' => 'Select Tags',
                    ),
                )
                    )
            );
        ?>
```

check this link it will help you more.

[Link1](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/723/creating-a-dependent-dropdown-from-scratch-in-yii2/)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951520/dependent-dropdown-yii2-how-to-do)

Comment: when you click on value of first dropdown value . it will update your 2nd dropdown according to that condition using ajax.

Comment: I edit my answer i  provide some links please check that , it will help you