# actually i use depentdropdown list with ajax but its not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

actually I am creating a dependent dropdown list but my ajax js_base_url not going to controller. I don't know what's a problem. table name is system_detail, and software_detail. and my controller name is SoftwaredetailController.php and SystemdetailController.php

my ajax code:

```
function getEmployee(id){
   $.ajax({ 
type:'POST',
url: JS_BASE_URL + 'systemdetail/get-employee',
data:{'id':id},
// dataType: 'text',
   success: function(data) {
       var options = '<option value="">Please Select</option>';       
    if ( data ) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);           
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            options +='<option value="'+json[i].system_id+'">'+json[i].system_id+'</option>'
            }
            $('#software_detail-system_id').html(options);
            return false;
        }
        $('#software_detail-system_id').html('');           
        $('#software_detail-system_id').html(options);

     },
});
```

}

my controller code:

```
public function actionGetEmployee()
    {  
        echo"<i am here>";die;

    $postData = Yii::$app->request->post();
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($postData['id']]);
    // die;
    $allSystemDetail = SystemDetail::find()
                ->where(['user_id' => $postData['id']])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
    if ($allSystemDetail){
        return json_encode($allSystemDetail); 
        }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

my dropdownlist list code:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList(
   ArrayHelper::map(Employee::find()->asArray()->all(),'id','employee_id'),
     [
        'onchange' => 'getEmployee(this.value)',
        'prompt'=>'Please Select',
     ])->label('Employee Id'); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'system_id')->dropDownList(
  ArrayHelper::map(SystemDetail::find()->asArray()->all(),'system_id','system_id'), 
 [ 'prompt' => 'Select System id']); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dependent dropdown yii2. How to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951520/dependent-dropdown-yii2-how-to-do)

Comment: first search on Google you will get lots of solutions . https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop check this link.

Comment: I already check on google and same method use second pc it is working. but here not working and error is " FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfil it.
(XHR): POST "

Comment: what is the value of `JS_BASE_URL + 'systemdetail/get-employee'`?

Comment: it is the base url value -- http://localhost/EMSystem/backend/web/systemdetail/get-employee

Comment: It should be `/EMSytem/systemdetail/get-employee`. Did you setup a vhost for your backend and frontend?

Comment: where is it use

Comment: You can refer this link on how to use yii2 advance template. [https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-using-the-advanced-application-template--cms-24994](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-using-the-advanced-application-template--cms-24994)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Url::to(['controller/action']) in JS code like :

```
function getEmployee(id){
   $.ajax({ 
          type:'POST',
          url: "<?php echo yii\helpers\Url::to(['systemdetail/get-employee']); //url for ajax call ?>",
         data:{'id':id},
         // dataType: 'text',
         success: function(data) {
                var options = '<option value="">Please Select</option>';       
                if ( data ) {
                   var json = JSON.parse(data);           
                   for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                   options +='<option value="'+json[i].system_id+'">'+json[i].system_id+'</option>'
                   }
                   $('#software_detail-system_id').html(options);
                   return false;
                 }
                 $('#software_detail-system_id').html('');           
                 $('#software_detail-system_id').html(options);

               },
         });
```

Comment: I use your but error show SCRIPT5009: 'getEmployee' is undefined

Comment: It will work if your script and controller are on same folder like frontend , backend

Comment: actually my solution is complete but i use second dependent list with 4 field. how it possible.