# how to get and display username in another form field when user select name from dropdownlist in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown

I want to display the lecturer username in another text input field form when the user selects the lecturer name in the drop-down list above.[image: this is my form]

this is my code for drop-down list lecturer name

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'LecturerName')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['category' => 'lecturer']),'fullname','fullname'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Lecturer']
        ) ?>
```

this is my code for lecturer username

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'LecUsername')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
```

I want to get and display the LecUsername based on the selected drop-down list above. the LecUsername is from the database.

Comment: See https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/723/creating-a-dependent-dropdown-from-scratch-in-yii2

Comment: See http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dependent dropdown yii2. How to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951520/dependent-dropdown-yii2-how-to-do)

Comment: @AntonRybalko thank you so much but i dont want to use another widget if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the dropdown you need to bind the `change` event for the dropdown to insert the value from the dropdown to the input text. And to make sure that you are inserting the `LecUsername` for the `LecturerName` you need to have the `LecUsername` as the value for the dropdown, means the drop-down data should have the `username` field as the index, currently you are using the `fullname` as the index and the value so change the code according to the field name you have for the username, i assume it is `username` for the example.

`ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['category' => 'lecturer']),'username','fullname')`

so your dropdown code will look like

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'LecturerName')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['category' => 'lecturer']),'username','fullname'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Lecturer']
        ) ?>
```

then add the below on top of your view file where you have the form

```
$ddId=Html::getInputId($model, 'LecturerName');
$inputId=Html::getInputId($model, 'LecUsername');

$js = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#{$ddId}").on('change',function(e){
        $("#{$inputId}").val($(this).val());
    });
});
JS;
 $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

A better way for dropdowns is to use the library [Kartik-v\select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) and use the event `pluginEvents` option to specify the event `select2:select`, your code should look like below in that case.

```
// Usage with ActiveForm and model
echo $form->field($model, 'LecturerName')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['category' => 'lecturer']),'username','fullname'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Lecturer'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents'=>[
        "select2:select" => 'function() { $("#{$ddId}").on('change',function(e){
             $("#{$inputId}").val($(this).val());
         }); }',
    ]
]);
```

Comment: what should i put here ? <?= $form->field($model, 'LecUsername')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>

Comment: this stays the same you dont need to change anything for the `LecUsername` @queenhoney

Comment: $ddId=Html::getInputId($model, 'LecturerName');
$inputId=Html::getInputId($model, 'LecUsername');

$js = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#{$ddId}").on('change',function(e){
        $("#{$inputId}").val($(this).val());
    });
});
JS;    did you mean i need to put this code inside view.php ? i already put it but nothing happen

Comment: @beginnerQueen yes, sorry i missed a line to register the script `$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);` i updated the answer above , it should work now

Comment: but if i used this code :<?= $form->field($model, 'LecturerName')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(User::findAll(['category' => 'lecturer']),'username','fullname'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Lecturer']
        ) ?>     the field for lecturer name will save the username and the LecUsername also save the username. i want to save the lecturer name in the lecturer name field.

Comment: @beginnerQueen well you need to have the `username` to be populated into the `LecUsername`, otherwise you need to send an ajax call to and action inside the controller and get the username against the user `LecturerName`.